# What Songs Are Best to Practice Reading Sheet Music and Playing Flute?

Tags: sheet-music, flute

To whom it may concern,

I am a high schooler that has been playing flute for a few years but struggles with reading advanced sheet music. What are some songs that are best to play, that will help advance my flute skills and reading skills? If there are any flute experts out here - please, help me with this: I cannot for the life of me get my F or G to get high. I know I have the same fingering, but what about blowing or mouth position makes the note higher?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site, flautist/fluter! It's not really set up as a site to recommend facilities/equipment, as you'll see when you read the help centre.

Comment: hi, your question got closed as you're asking it in the wrong place but just a tip, the last two sentences seem to introduce a totally separate question so for best results you should consider researching/asking that separately when you take this up again. That second question looks more suitable for asking here, although I'd suggest researching it first as there may already be answers here on that.